# Different ways to initialize char array, are they correct?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, variable-assignment

I am using two type of declaration for char array in C as:

1. `char buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";`
2. `char buf[BUFFLEN];  buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";`

Where `BUFFLEN` being some constant.

When I compiled the second way, I get warning but no error as

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Can someone please explain me a difference. I checked few posts on it but really having hard time in understanding it completely.

Comment: `char buf[BUFFLEN];=`...just WT* is that? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** they both are not *initialization*, the first one is **[initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming))**, the second one is (an attempt to) **[assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))**.

---

**The first case,** is an attempt to define a `char` array and initialize the contents with the string literal "Hello, I am client :)". The syntax

```
 char buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";
```

is good, as we're allowed   <sup>***## Note 1***</sup>  to supply an initializer in form of a string literal to a `char` array. This snippet is a valid one, so we're good there.

However, in **the second case,**

```
  char buf[BUFFLEN];
  buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";
```

the second statement is wrong, as

- `buf[BUFFLEN]` is out of bound memory access, it's [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). This actually causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

  -- *FWIW, C uses 0-based indexing for arrays, so for an array defined with size `BUFFLEN` will have valid indexes ranging from `0` to `BUFFLEN-1`.*
- (*considering*) The syntax `buf[BUFFLEN - <whatever>] = "some string";` is also invalid, as this is a constraint violation <sup>***## Note 2***</sup> . Check the data types.

  -- The LHS is of type `char`, you're trying to assign a value of type `char []` (which decays to `char*`) and the assignment is invalid C. You need to *copy* the content, make use of [`strcpy()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) or alike.

---

**## Note 1:**

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

**## Note 2:**

`C11`, chapter §6.5.16.1, *Simple assignment Constraints*

> One of the following shall hold:<sup>112)</sup>
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has
>     arithmetic type;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union
>     type compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
>     the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
>     pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
>     to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
>     the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer
>     to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of
>     void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to
>     by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null
>     pointer constant; or
> - the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool, and the right is a
>     pointer.

Comment: buf[BUFFLEN] is a char in case 2.

Answer (score 8):

```
char buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";
```

This creates a character array and initializes it with the contents of the string literal.

```
char buf[BUFFLEN];

buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";
```

This creates an uninitialized character array, and then preforms an out of bounds access. The behavior of this snippet is undefined.

Comment: buf[0] = "Hello, I am client :)"; would also be faulty right?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assign a c-string to an array, you can only initialize it when you declare it, so

```
char buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";
```

It is ok.

But if you want to set it runtime you must use a function as [strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy):

```
strcpy(buf, "Hello, I am client :)");
```

Obviously you must ensure, at least, that

```
BUFFERLEN >= strlen("Hello, I am client :)") + 1
```

**EDIT**

To have a safe solution you should

```
char buf[BUFFLEN] = {0};

snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%*s", (int)(sizeof(buf)-1), "Hello, I am client :)");
```

With  [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) you grant:

- That output string i alsways null terminated
- that the size of buf is respected due to `sizeof(buf)`
- Moreover with `"%*s"` format specifier and `(int)(sizeof(buf)-1)` you force to copy a number of chars that fits your `buf` array.

Comment: Sorry, but where did OP try to assign to _array_?

Comment: @SouravGhosh As far as I can understand, where he wrote `buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";`

Comment: @LPs Yaah, I get it now. Thanks Pal.

Comment: Better to use `strncpy` and forget unsafe `strcpy` forever.

Comment: @j123b567 Not really safer, as [Man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) says: _The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied. Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest **will not be null-terminated**_

Comment: @LPs Is there any problem to use  `strncpy(buf, "Hello, I am client :)", BUFFERLEN - 1); buf[BUFFERLEN -1] = 0;`?

Comment: @LPs It is definitely safer than pure `strcpy` and pray that the second argument is shorter than `BUFFERLEN` or do additional slow `strlen` to be sure. In case, text is longer then `BUFFERLEN-1` what will you do? Manual `memcpy` and many `if`s, ... no thanks.

Comment: @j123b567 or better `snprintf(buf, sizeof(test), "%*s", (int)(sizeof(buf)) "Hello, I am client :)" );` BTW what I mean is: OP level is too low and I suspect too much infos at this moment can only confuse him/her.

Comment: @LPs Yes! Or this nice/ugly solution. But `strcpy` is no-go.

Comment: That use of %*s to null terminate. Amazing!

Answer (score 2):

In the example you provided, 
1.char buf[BUFFLEN];   (compiler initializes the data by default even though you didn't )
2. buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)"; (it treats it as a assignment operation and you cannot assign one array of characters to another array of characters like this language doesn't allow)

you can use strcpy 
char buf[BUFFLEN]
strncpy(buf, "Hello, I am client :)", BUFFLEN);

Answer (score 2):

`= "Hello, I am client :)";` is a special way of initialising arrays of characters, which only works at the definition of the array, i.e. in the line with the type (`char   ...[]`).
It creates the array and fills it with the characters in the string, before the start of main, during the memory setup.

The second method

- defines an array of char, without initialising it `char buf[BUFFLEN];`
- makes a write access just one behind the array (what other answers commented on ) `buf[BUFFLEN] =`
- attempts to write to that "char" at that illegal location  ...
- ... a pointer to a string constant `"Hello, I am client :)";`

After the initialisation-at-definition, strings need to be copied to arrays of char, by using a function, e.g. `strncpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say BUFFLEN = 20.

So, according to your code char buff[BUFFLEN]="Hello, I am client :)";

It creates an array of chars of size 20 and assigns your string. then if you write 
char buff[BUFFLEN];
buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";

you are actually attempting to access or initialize buf[20] which cause to array out of bound. because buf can be access from 0 index to 19.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I understand that concept completely. Let's say if BUFFLEN = 100 then what? I am doing some socket programming and I see difference between output when using these 2 ways.
1st way works perfect and I get proper message at server side while when doing with second way, I just get @C as output which I assume is some pointer reference.

Comment: size of char is 1. if u write buff[20]="abc" (lets say) then it not works

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";
```

Valid character array initialization but  do not specify the bound of a string intitialized with a string literal because the compiler will automatically allocate sufficient space for entire string literal,including the terminating null character.

c11 - 6.7.8 : paragraph 14:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>   character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

and in second,

```
char buf[BUFFLEN];

buf[BUFFLEN] = "Hello, I am client :)";
```

Illegal initialization of character array.